# Float and int members in a union does not show values

Tags: c

I am trying to understand union and here is a example code I wrote,

```
#include <stdio.h>

union god{
    int body;
    float spirit;
};

union god human;

int main(void)
{
    float malice = 5.4;
    human.spirit = malice;
    printf("%ld %ld\n", sizeof(float), sizeof(int));
    printf("%d %f\n", human.body, human.spirit);
    return 0;
}
```

I expected 5 5.4 as output, because same memory is used for int and float types, I should be able to store both in same place.

However printing those values doesn't show my guess.

```
4 4
1085066445 5.400000
```

Output does not show both values as **5 5.4**.

int and float both have same size, so same memory is used for holding them.

1.But why the output is like this?

2.Am I missing some float, union, printf related basics?

Comment: This is how a `union` works: All components share the same storage. Hence, if you assign one of them the others may not be used (or at least with certain restrictions only -> [type punning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_punning)).

Comment: I think its this way, whatever you assign to any member of a union you can see the value interpreted in member's ways. Changes done on one will be reflected in all as the storage is same.

Comment: If you want to convert `float` to `int` then use `float spirit = 5.4; int body = (int)spirit;` (without `union`). The value `1085066445` shows how the 32 bits of `float spirit;` would "look like" when interpreted as `int` value. If you find this confusing, please, have a look at [IEEE Standard 754 Floating Point Numbers](http://steve.hollasch.net/cgindex/coding/ieeefloat.html).

Comment: @Scheff: No need to cast in C.

Comment: @alk Well, it's done implicitly as well. But, for pedagogical reasons it might be acceptable in this case... ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value in a float is stored in a special format. In the most common format, it is encoded with one bit for a sign, eight bits for an exponent, and 23 bits for the significand (a fraction). For 5.4, the sign bit is 0 (for positive), the exponent is 2 and is encoded as 129 (127 is added; the exponent is stored with a bias), and the fraction is 1.35000002384185791015625, using the bits 0x2ccccd. (Those are the fraction minus one, then multiplied by 2<sup>23</sup>.) Put together, the sign bit, the exponent bits, and the significand bits form 0x40accccd. In decimal, that is 1085066445.

So, when you store 5.4 in the `float` member of the union, the bits 0x40accccd are written to the storage. When you read the `int` member, those bits are interpreted as 1085066445.

Comment: Even got the hidden-bit part, that's a whole lot in one paragraph `:)`

Comment: I understand now its interpretation done by IEEE. This site also tells a nice way to do same, http://www.log2base2.com/storage/how-float-values-are-stored-in-memory.html

Answer (score 2):

For most of the implementation, `int` and `float` use essentially different representation in terms of bit. If you interpret the same bit sequence in `float` as `int`, the result is meaningless. You can't expect a `float` representation of `5.4` is also a `int` representation of `5`.

See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Internal_representation) some typical implementation of `floating point`, and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) a typical representation of `int`.

Comment: So can I assume that a value stored in any 4 byte storage in a machine, is just 1 step of representing that float value. Rest of the part, like getting to the actual value is different in hardware ways?

Comment: No. It is the whole part, but they are represented by different and irrelevant standards, so the results are not mutually interpretable.

Comment: @nikhilchaubey: Bits in memory are just bits in memory. They are not inherently `float` values or `int` values. They only have meaning when we choose to interpret them in a particular way. Normally, the compiler does this for you. When you define `int x`, the compiler sets aside some storage for an `int` and automatically interprets the bits using the `int` format whenever you read it. When you declare `float x`, the compiler automatically interprets them using the `float` format. When you use a union, you tell the compiler to write one way and interpret another.